# Problem with constraints of NMaximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

I am using `NMaximize` to solve the following problem.

```
Mh = 95.;
MH = 125.18;
v = 246.22;
l1[a_, b_,M12_] := (Sin[a]^2 MH^2+Cos[a]^2 Mh^2 - (M12) Tan[b])/(Cos[b]^2 v^2);
l2[a_, b_,M12_] := (Cos[a]^2 Mh^2+Sin[a]^2 MH^2 - ((M12)/Tan[b]))/(Sin[b]^2 v^2);
l3[a_, b_, MC_,M12_] := ((Sin[2. a]) (Mh^2 - MH^2) + 2. (M12)+2. (MC^2) Sin[2. b])/(Sin[2. b] v^2);
l4[b_, MC_, MA_,M12_] := (MA^2 - 2. (MC^2) - (2 (M12)/Sin[2b]))/(v^2);
l5[b_, MA_, M12_] := ((2. (M12)/Sin[2. b]) - MA^2)/v^2;

Pert[a_, b_, MC_, MA_, M12_] := Abs[l1[a, b, M12]] <= 4.*N[Pi, 4] && Abs[l2[a, b, M12]] <= 4.*N[Pi, 4] && Abs[l3[a, b, MC, M12]] <= 4.*N[Pi, 4] && Abs[l4[b, MC, MA, M12]] <= 4.*N[Pi, 4] && 
  Abs[l5[b, MA, M12]] <= 4.*N[Pi, 4]

Mct[a_, b_, MC_, MA_, M12_] := MC + 0*(a + b + MC + MA + M12)
NMaximize[{Mct[a, b, MC, MA, M12],Pert[a, b, MC, MA, M12]}, {a, b, MC, MA, M12}]
```

The result is:

```
{628.097, {a -> 453.086, b -> 427.368, MC -> 628.097, MA -> -589.965, M12 -> 254.967}}
```

which seems like there is no problem.

Then, I put the result back into the constraint `Pert`.
It shows:

```
Pert[453.08648222747297, 427.368470714907, 628.097417629226,-589.965030031508, 254.96714952092478]
False
```

That means the result doesn't obey the constraint.
Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Not the real problem, but you should better replace `Beta` by another symbol; `Beta` is the built-in symbol for the Euler beta function.

Comment: Please check your code, I can't reproduce your results. In your constraint `Pert` I found `<...4.*N[Pi, 4]`. What 's your intention reducing the accuracy? Better substitute `<...4Pi`. one last remark: If you check your constraint by substituting the result there might be rounding effects causing `False`.   Try  `Pert[Alpha, Beta, MC, MA, M12] /.LessEqual->Subtract`

Comment: Hi. I change Beta to b and Alpha to a. The result show different value but checking with the constraint still returns `False`. Also tried  `Pert[Alpha, Beta, MC, MA, M12] /.LessEqual->Subtract`

Comment: ...and `Pert[Alpha, Beta, MC, MA, M12] /.LessEqual->Subtract `  gives a list of small negative numbers?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann No. It returns `False`

Comment: @Panithi Nakkhruea It would ease helping if you provide the functioning code

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Sorry. I don't understand that. What does it mean "the functioning code"?

Comment: @The code you posted in your question doesn't run !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Edited. Please tell me if it still can't run. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you name the result of NMaximize `opt` you can check the constraints as follows:

```
Pert[a, b, MC, MA, M12] /. LessEqual -> Subtract /. opt[[2]]
(*-12.3711 && -8.19684*10^-10 && 1.31202*10^-11 && -1.26459 &&-10.8498*)
```

Every  constraint is negativ! Second and third are very small and cause the `False` in

```
Pert[a, b, MC, MA, M12] /. opt[[2]]
(* False *)
Pert[a, b, MC, MA, M12] /. And -> List /. opt[[2]]
(*{True, True, False, True, True}*)
```

Comment: So, how can I fix this? And what does the very small value mean?

Comment: You don't have to fix it! It is a numerical accuracy issue.

Comment: Could you explain me what the result of `Pert[a, b, MC, MA, M12] /. LessEqual -> Subtract /. opt[[2]]` means?

Comment: That means   the inequalitis `a<=b` is changed  to `a-b`.

Comment: Ok, I see. That means it should show only negative value or zero. The third value is very small (approaching zero), so this makes it return `False`, right? Could you edit your answer and add the explanation on it? Thank you so much for your help.